# Sent a message from C# to QT

Tags: c#, c++, sockets, tcpclient, qtcpserver

I need to send a string line from a C# client (3.5) to a QT server. Everything works ok except one thing that on the server side I have to check a size of the line which is first 2 bytes. (I can't just make an infinite loop of listing the client). I try to put the size of the line to a first byte of the line but it reads wrongly on the server side. So the question is **how to put a length of the string into first 2 bytes of the string?**.

In QT it's done like this:

```
QByteArray arrBlock;
QDataStream out(&arrBlock, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
out << quint16(0) << "string";
out.device() -> seek(0);
out << **quint16(arrBlock.size() - sizeof(quint16));**
socket->write(arrBlock);
```

but in C# it's only

```
NetworkStream serverStream;
byte[] bytes = ...GetBytes("string");
serverStream.write
serverStream.flush
```

I couldn't find the way to write size to a message to the server.

Comment: First of all, your question says "last 2 bytes" but the code says you want "first 2 bytes"? Secondly, why not put the actual data into a collection that have a length property, like a `QString`? Then you can write the length and data at once.

Comment: No I mean like `QString data("string"); out << qint16(data.length()) << data; socket->write(...);``

Comment: Do you mean something like "3|abc"? on the server side it won't be read correctly.        `code` 
            in >> block;
//here it will be more than 10 symbols number.        
        if(socket->bytesAvailable()<(qint16)block)
        {/*I got here where I shouldn't be cuz my block is actually 3 bytes. I need to get to else and it's possible to do having written actual size of a line*/            
            QByteArray data;
            data=socket->read(socket->bytesAvailable());
            tmp.append(data);
            if (tmp.size() < (int)block)
                return;
        } `code`

Comment: I didn't find anything like out << ... in C#. That stuff with streams I have to do in C#